# opencv: what does foundWeights mean in virtual void detectMultiScale(..)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'd like to use this version of the function
**CV_WRAP virtual void detectMultiScale**(*const Mat& img, CV_OUT vector& foundLocations,*
                                  **CV_OUT vector& foundWeights**, *double hitThreshold=0,
                                  Size winStride=Size(), Size padding=Size(), double scale=1.05,
                                  double finalThreshold=2.0,bool useMeanshiftGrouping = false*) const;

What does foundWeights mean, what does each value represent? It is not correlated to the size of the boxes. What else is it good for?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [here](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/HOG-td7294077.html), `foundWeights` are the normalized scores of every object detected:

```
weight_i = score_i / sum(score, from 1 = N), if score_i > 0
```

Comment: thanks, normalized should mean a value 0..1, but I get values >1. typically in range 0..2. Nevertheless I still don't know what it is good/useful for.

Comment: my interpretation of this value would be, the higher the value, the better the object got detected.